# Do indexes work if only a prefix of query fields is indexed in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing, mongodb-query, mongo-index

I have a schema like this:

```js
{
   name: string,
   age: number,
   marks: number
}
```

And I have a compound index on `name` and `age` fields.

```js
{ name: 1, age: 1}
```

If I have a query like this:

```
collection.find({ name: 'X', age: 10, marks: 100 })
```

Will the indexes on name and age help mongo to optimise the query?

If I have a separate index on marks `{ marks: 1 }`, will it work now?

Or do I need to have compound index on all three to make it work `{ name: 1, age: 1, marks: 1 }` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `{ name: 1, age: 1 }`
   Index on `name and age` will narrow down the search documents first, but it will still need to scan through those matched documents to find the ones with marks equal to 100
2. Separate `{ marks: 1 }`
   Index on `marks` will narrow down the search documents first, but it will still need to scan through those matched documents to find the ones by filtering name and age
3. `{ name: 1, age: 1, marks: 1 }`
   This index can fully cover the query. MongoDB can efficiently use this index to filter based on all three fields: name, age, and marks. It will not require a collection scan

So to answer your question, you need compound indexing on all three.
I hope this covers your concern

Comment: If `{name:1, age:1}` can narrow down the search, it's fine for my use case. Only 2 or 3 documents will match the name, age combo. I am just worried if the indexes will be no-op in this case and mongo will search the entire collection. Also I don't think your second point is correct. Indexes only work if the fields  in the query are prefix of the compound index